# Coded UI test support for tee chart

Tags: .net, visual-studio, teechart, codeplex

We are using sample tee chart in our application . We could able to automate tee chart to some basic level through Coded UI test framework

Our Question is, Is tee chart supports for CUITe (Coded UI Test Enhanced)? (CUITe is a thin layer deveolped on top of Microsoft Visual Studio Team test's Coded UI Test engine which helps reduce code,CodePlex Product)

Please let us know.

Thank you.

Regards,

Praveen

Answer (score 2):

TeeChart for .NET is a native custom control, 100% written in managed C# code. TeeChart for .NET doesn't implement any specific layer to support Coded UI Test enhanced. So, I'd expect [CUITe](https://cuite.codeplex.com/) to work fine with TeeChart for .NET if it supports custom .NET class libraries. However, [looking at the documentation](https://cuite.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Support%20for%20Telerik%20controls&referringTitle=Documentation), it seems its CUITe that needs to add functionality to support specific controls so you might better ask them.